# Hibernate mapping join on one column of constants table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 2 tables, the first one is quite variable, the second one contains only constants:

```
USER.ID   USER.NAME   USER.USER_TYPE (FK on USER_TYPE.ID)
INT       VARCHAR(64) INT(1)
----------------------------------
1         Alex        3
2         Jane        1
3         Carl        3
```

---

```
USER_TYPE.ID   USER_TYPE.VALUE
INT(1)         VARCHAR(64)
------------------------------
1              PENDING
2              REGISTERED
3              BANNED
4              ACTIVE
```

The foreign key `USER.USER_TYPE` is required and refering to a primary key `USER_TYPE.ID` in table `USER_TYPE` (one-to-one relation). Here is my mapping in Hibernate.

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)   
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_TYPE") 
    private UserType userType;
}
```

UserType.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_TYPE")
public class UserType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;
}
```

My goal is to keep the enumerated values in the database. How to map `UserType`'s value instead of id to `User` and validate it? I want to pass the constant VALUE to the String instead of its ID.

```
private String userType;
```

The expected result of the first user would be:

```
User[id=1, name=Alex, userType=Banned]
User[id=2, name=Jane, userType=Pending]
User[id=3, name=Carl, userType=Banned]
```

---

My attempt was to use this annotation on definition of table twice with both colums switched

```
@SecondaryTable(name="USER_TYPE", 
    pkJoinColumns={@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="USER_TYPE")}
)
```

and get the VALUE with

```
@Column(table="USER_TYPE", name="VALUE")
private String UserType;
```

however it leads to the error

> Unable to find column with logical name: USER_TYPE in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(USER) and its related supertables and secondary tables

Comment: in table User we can map the column @JoinColumn(name = "<any column fo user type table>")

Comment: @jeetendraMandal I think you misunderstood my question. I have edited it for sure.

Comment: why don't you use a derived property or a simple property accessor in the User entity ? 
For example
`
    @Transient
    public string getUserType() {
      return userType.value;
    }
`
Can you elaborate your uncommon/weird goal :) ?

Comment: @gtosto How is this problem weird? It's just passing constant value based on its ID since I don't want to use enumerations id DB, it's quite common. I have edited my question a bit. Would you give me a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change the relation from `@OneToOne` to [@ManyToOne](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) as `UserType` can be used by one or many `User` and `User` can have one and one `UserType`.

Secondly use [referencedColumnName](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch07.html#naturalid-mapping) which references :

> The name of the column referenced by this foreign key column.

So `User` entity will be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)   
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_TYPE", referencedColumnName = "VALUE") 
    private UserType userType;    
}
```

In `UserType` you should apply a unique constraint using [@NaturalId](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch07.html#naturalid-mapping) to `value` field + do not provide its setter, to prevent duplicate values as It may lead to inconsistency:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_TYPE")
public class UserType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @NaturalId 
    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;
}
```

Hope it solves the issue!

Comment: Looks great, I'll give it a try. Just a random though.. what if I'd need no tone, but two (or more) values ` String value` and `value2` from the 2nd table?

Comment: I didn't get your question, could you elaborate more? if you would like to get the string value `UserType.value`, you can declare a method `getValue` in `Ùser` entity that get the String value based on the `userType`, may be it's what you want!!??!!

Comment: Yes, you answered me well. I mean, what if in the future I'd like to extend the table `USER_TYPE` by one more column `VALUE_2` containing for ex. description. Then, I would like to have mapped `String userTypeValue` on `VALUE` and `String userTypeValue2` on `VALUE_2`. Result for example `User[id=1, name=Alex, userTypeValue=Banned, userTypeValue2=This user is banned]`

Comment: When using entities with a relationship, you can use any property of the other side of the relationship. So all `UserType` properties are accessible from User entity, you need just add a correspondent method that will return the desired value, even though I discouraged to do so (to prevent redundancy), as you can use a `User.getUserType()` method and extract whatever property you want.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerations could be simpler:

```
enum UserType {
    PENDING,
    REGISTERED,
    BANNED,
    ACTIVE
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @javax.persistence.Enumerated
    private UserType userType;
}
```

If you really need separated table and @OneToOne relation, you can use @Formula from Hibernate:

```
@Formula("(select ut.value from user_type ut where ut.ID = USER_TYPE)")
private String userType;
```

Comment: Finally solved with Enum, both of your answer are working well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to note that, by default, [@Enumerated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html) will store ordinal value in your database, if you wanna store String value use `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For this really special requirement you could use [SecondaryTable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-jpa-secondarytable) annotation.
That is, you don't need UserType entity, but declare attribute userType as String in User entity with column mapping to the secondary table "USER_TYPE".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you use `ManyToOne` relation. and Not `CascadeType.ALL` if you are not planning update or delete on `USER_TYPE` table.

If you do not need adding new `UserTypes` frequently use enum for it. It will just work as you want.

Second solution: As long as `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` you can add A transient field and return value of `UserType` in getter.

Comment: Normaly you have limited numbers of UserTypes like 5 - 6, like in example but have lots of user like thousands, So many users share one UserType,  ManyToOne.

Comment: Well, would you give me a working example? I have tried to use `@JoinColumn`, however type mismatch happens.